# Retrieving data from multidimensional array from arrays.xml

Tags: android, xml, multidimensional-array

Suppose I'm having a three-dimensional array in my arrays.xml, something like

```
<string-array name="level1-1">
    <item name="id">a</item>
    <item name="id">b</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="level1-2">
    <item name="id">c</item>
    <item name="id">d</item>
</string-array>
<array name="level1">
    <item>@array/level1-1</item>
    <item>@array/level1-2</item>
</array>
<string-array name="level2-1">
    <item name="id">e</item>
    <item name="id">f</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="level2-2">
    <item name="id">g</item>
    <item name="id">h</item>
</string-array>
<array name="level2">
    <item>@array/level2-1</item>
    <item>@array/level2-2</item>
</array>
<array name="top_level">
    <item>@array/level1</item>
    <item>@array/level2</item> 
</array>
```

Now I'm looking to read it inside of my Android application. From reading similar questions here I've made a conclusion that TypedArrays are the proper way of retrieving data and while it's not hard to retrieve the whole 3-dimensional chunk as a TypedArray, it doesn't seem like there are any instruments for retrieving another TypedArrays using their IDs.

So how it is possible to retrieve a 2-dimensional "slice" out of a 3-dimensional TypedArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I've already figured it out by myself. Some Java code to perform the task of retrieving the "slice" like in the example shown above:

```
public TypedArray getSlice(TypedArray ta, long k)    {
    Resources res = getResources();

    int id = ta.getResourceId((int)k, 0);
    return res.obtainTypedArray(id);
}
```

As with the example given in the question the function call should be `getSlice(array, K)`.

Answer (score 1):

The firs you can get your array from xml

```
   List<String> tablel1-1 = Array.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.table1-1));
   List<String> tablel1-2 = Array.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.table1-1));

   HashMap<List<String>,List<String>> level1 = new HashMap<List<String>,List<String>(table1-1,table1-2);


   List<String> tablel2-1 = Array.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.table2-1));
   List<String> tablel2-2 = Array.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.table2-1));

   HashMap<List<String>,List<String>> level2 = new HashMap<List<String>,List<String>(table2-1,table2-2);
```

Finally you can create the HashMap with two HashMaps if necessary.

```
    Hashmap<Hashmap<List<String>,List<String>>,Hashmap<List<String>,List<String>>> top_level = new
                 Hashmap<Hashmap<List<String>,List<String>>,Hashmap<List<String>,List<String>>>(level1,level2);
```

Comment: While this works with the said example I'm not sure this will work with bigger arrays or more dimensions, I just tried to give the easiest example. Let's generalize: we have a TypedArray array with N dimensions and each dimension has M(i) elements where i belongs to [1..n]. We are given an index K. How do we retrieve array[K] using arrays.xml only to retrieve the array itself?

Comment: ArrayList in Java has a get(int index) method.  int is a signed 32 bit value, with a maximum value of 2,147,483,647.

Comment: A HashMap uses an array which always has a size that is a power of two, so it can be at most 2^30 = 1073741824 elements

Comment: Right, but what would you do if there were, say, 5 dimensions with 10 elements in each? I'm looking for a more universal approach.